# Jquery Datatables client side optimization

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatables

I'm using [Jquery datatables library](https://www.datatables.net/) since a long time in server side processing but I encountered lot of problem when I use filter search because the rendered data isn't the same value of the database value.

So I have a new project and I decide to use datatables client side. So I have an ajax call to get all my data. But php is really slow if I do queries  with relationship on 100 000 rows.

Then the idea is to use a limit to display some data to the client and processing in background and display all result when it's ok. I see [deferRender](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/defer_render.html) method in datatables documentation but I don't see any changes.

So I do an first ajax call with a limit parameter, I display the results and I do a second ajax call without limit parameter, then I display all result.

The problem with that is the number of the total record... When the table is populate with the first call I have the total record of the limit so I don't have the real total record number. It's initialized at the second time.

How can I edit the total record number to display the final pagination and the final "Showing x to y of z entries" at the first call ? Or maybe I'm doing wrong and there is another good way to do what I want.

Here is my datatable initialization :

```
$('#foldersTable').DataTable({
    dom: "t<'col-sm-5'i><'col-sm-7'p>",
    autoWidth: false,
    serverSide: false,
    aaSorting: [[2, 'desc']],
    createdRow: addDataAttr,
    drawCallback: keepSelectedRow,
    rowId: 'id',
    lengthChange: false,
    iDisplayLength: 10,
    deferRender: true,
    initComplete: function(settings, json) {
        $('.table-responsive').show();
        limit = false;
        $('#foldersTable').DataTable().ajax.reload(null, false);
    },
    ajax: {
        url: 'getFolders',
        method: 'POST',
        dataSrc: checkSessionDT,
        data : { "limit" : function() { return limit; } }
    },
    language: {
        lengthMenu: datatable_lang.lengthMenu,
        zeroRecords: datatable_lang.zeroRecords,
        info: datatable_lang.info,
        infoEmpty: datatable_lang.infoEmpty,
        infoFiltered: datatable_lang.infoFiltered,
        search: datatable_lang.search,
        searchPlaceholder: datatable_lang.searchPlaceholder,
        paginate: {
            previous: datatable_lang.paginate.previous,
            next: datatable_lang.paginate.next
        }
    },
    columns: [
        {data: "Column A", width:"20%"},
        {data: "Column B", width:"20%", orderData:[1, 0]},
        {data: "Column C", render: renderFunction, width:"20%", orderData:[2, 0], type: "date-euro"},
        {data: "Column D", width:"20%", orderData:[3, 0]},
        {data: "Column E", width:"20%", orderData:[4, 0]}
    ]
});
```

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Server side processing is *always* better for large recordsets. I'd suggets you spend time fixing the original issues with that instead of creating new problems by moving the paging logic client side

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I understand your answer but there are lot of problems with server side processing. Imagine you have a boolean 0 or 1 in your database and you display `Online` / `Offline` to the client, when he will search Online into the seach box the server will not find the rows. And the server side processing is really slow if you have a bad connection, each sort, each search etc... will be really slow. Maybe it's better to load all data and get a smooth client side table.

Comment: It will be **much** slower to download 100,000 records to the client, then attempt to search through them in JS before updating the UI. You are just wasting development time on a massively flawed solution if you attempt to do this.

Comment: If the server side processing is really slow if you have a bad connection, imagine how slow it's going to be if you try to send the huge dataset over to the client first! Most users dislike having to wait to see something happening; it's better to send them the first page of search results and then they can interact with them, filter, etc., rather than making them wait for the whole lot to be sent over before any of the javascript functionality works.

Comment: That was the easier and the faster solution for me because our customers want to use columns filtering a lot and I don't have solution to match the rendered data with database value. And the export excel is easier too.

Comment: If I do server side then I have to create custom search element. For example put a checkbox when there is a boolean rendered data. Use datepicker for rendered date with moment.js. etc... But I don't know how much time it will take to do that. But... you really recommand me to use server side processing so I'll try to do that

Comment: The old adage applies here; 'Easy, fast or good. You can only choose two'